# register_uninstall_hook not working on wordpress plugin uninstall

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi there i make a plugin, now i want that when a user deactivate the plugin, all the functions and posts and option values and meta values also be deleted.

I write a hook and make a file where i delete all the values, but it did not work, i use this hook

```
register_uninstall_hook('foo_uninstall.php', $callback);
```

Is there any other hook to use for this purpose.

Here is my foo_uninstall.php code

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$del_prefix = $wpdb->prefix;

//if uninstall not called from WordPress exit
if(!defined('WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN'))
    exit();

//=========> Delete foo Options
    delete_option('foo_theme_directory');
    delete_option('foo_plugin_slug');
    delete_option('foo_article_qty');
    delete_option('foo_search_setting');
    delete_option('foo_breadcrumbs_setting');
    delete_option('foo_sidebar_setting');
    delete_option('foo_comments_setting');
    delete_option('foo_bgcolor');
    delete_option('widget_foo_article_widget');
    delete_option('foo_cat_children');

//=========> Get and Delete Foo Page
    $foo_get_page = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$del_prefix."posts WHERE post_type='page' And 

post_content = '[foo_article]' And post_name = 'article'",ARRAY_A );

    $fooPageID = $foo_get_page['ID'];

    $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM ".$del_prefix."postmeta WHERE post_id = '$fooPageID'");

    $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM ".$del_prefix."posts WHERE post_title Like '%article%' And post_type = 

'page'");

//=========> Delete foo Terms and Taxonomies
    $foo_Find_tax = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM ".$del_prefix."term_taxonomy WHERE 

taxonomy='foo_article'",ARRAY_A );
    $fooTaxID = $foo_Find_tax[0]['term_taxonomy_id'];

    foreach($foo_Find_tax as $foo_find_tax){
    $fooTaxID = $foo_find_tax['term_taxonomy_id'];

    $delete_foo_relations = $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM ".$del_prefix."term_relationships WHERE 

term_taxonomy_id='$fooTaxID'");
    $delete_foo_tax = $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM ".$del_prefix."term_taxonomy WHERE 

term_taxonomy_id='$fooTaxID'");
    $delete_foo_terms = $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM ".$del_prefix."terms WHERE term_id='$fooTaxID'");
    }

//=========> Delete terms_order From wp_terms
    $wpdb->query("ALTER TABLE ".$del_prefix."terms DROP `terms_order`");

//=========> Delete comments of articles
    $foo_comments = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID FROM ".$del_prefix."posts WHERE post_type = 

'foo_article'");

    $foo_comment_id = $foo_comments->ID;

    foreach($foo_comments as $foo_comment){
        $foo_comment_id = $foo_comment->ID;
        $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM ".$del_prefix."comments WHERE comment_post_ID='$foo_comment_id'");
    }

//=========> Delete All Articles and Attachments
    $foo_all_articles = new WP_Query('post_type=foo_article&posts_per_page=-1');

    if($foo_all_articles){
        while($foo_all_articles->have_posts()) :
            $foo_all_articles->the_post();
            $fooID = get_the_id();

            $foo_del_args = array('post_parent' => $fooID);
            $foo_attachments = get_children($foo_del_args);

            if($foo_attachments){
                foreach($foo_attachments as $foo_attachment){
                    wp_delete_attachment($foo_attachment->ID, true);
                }
            }
            wp_delete_post($fooID, true);
        endwhile;
    }

//=========> Remove all files and images
    unlink(get_template_directory()."/foo_articles.php");
    unlink(get_template_directory()."/foo_style.css");
    unlink(get_template_directory()."/single-foo_articles.php");
    unlink(get_template_directory()."/taxonomy-foo_cat.php");
    unlink(get_template_directory()."/foo_search.php");

?>
```

Comment: What "did not work"? Everything? What debug have you done?

Comment: everything not working @brasofilo

Comment: Not even `delete_option`? Did you try running the sql queries directly on phpMyAdmin?

Comment: not even delete options ....... Yes i run the queries

Answer (score 1):

try [register deactivation hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_deactivation_hook) instead of register uninstall hook . Please do [refer here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25910/uninstall-activate-deactivate-a-plugin-typical-features-how-to/25979#25979) for more.

```
register_uninstall_hook(    __FILE__, 'foo_on_uninstall' );

function foo_on_uninstall() {
   // write your uninstall code
}
```

Comment: can i do this .... register_uninstall_hook(    __FILE__.'foo_uninstall.php', 'foo_on_uninstall' );

Comment: just copy the code of foo_uninstall.php to foo_on_uninstall()   or include the foo_uninstall.php into the foo_on_uninstall().

Answer (score 1):

Remove the part

```
if(!defined('WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN'))
exit();
```

According to the [Plugin Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/uninstall-methods/#method-2-uninstall-php), `WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN` is not defined when uninstall is performed by register_uninstall_hook().